# Returning a query from a do block

Tags: postgresql

All I want to do is be able to use a `do` block to set some variables and then return a query to `STDOUT` using those variables.

```
DO $$
DECLARE book_name TEXT;
DECLARE book_slug TEXT;
BEGIN
  book_name := 'Ise Monogatari';
  book_slug := 'ise';

  SELECT bk.id,
    bk.created_at,
    bk.updated_at,
    bk.title,
    bk.japanese_title,
    bk.content,
    bk.description,
    'public/cjp/' || book_slug || '/images/cover.png' cover_image_path,
    'public/cjp/' || book_slug || '/images/title.png' title_image_path,
    'public/cjp/' || book_slug || '/images/thumb_left.png' thumbnail_path,
    'public/cjp/' || book_slug || '/images/background.png' background_image_path,
    bk.about,
    bk.published
  FROM books bk
  WHERE bk.title = book_name;
END $$;
```

I get the following error:

```
[42601] ERROR: query has no destination for result data
Hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
Where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 8 at SQL statement
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot return any result from a DO command. [The documentation says](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html) (emphasis added):

> The code block is treated as though it were the body of a function with no parameters, **returning void.**

You can use a common table expression:

```
WITH args(book_name, book_slug) AS (
    VALUES ('Ise Monogatari', 'ise')
)

  SELECT bk.id,
    bk.created_at,
    bk.updated_at,
    bk.title,
    bk.japanese_title,
    bk.content,
    bk.description,
    'public/cjp/' || book_slug || '/images/cover.png' cover_image_path,
    'public/cjp/' || book_slug || '/images/title.png' title_image_path,
    'public/cjp/' || book_slug || '/images/thumb_left.png' thumbnail_path,
    'public/cjp/' || book_slug || '/images/background.png' background_image_path,
    bk.about,
    bk.published
  FROM books bk
  CROSS JOIN args
  WHERE bk.title = book_name;
```

Comment: Thank you! As always, I should have read the manual more carefully.

Comment: At first reading one do not know what to look for. But fortunately there is stackoverflow!

Comment: If you want to return some date from do bloack you can use GUC or TEMP TABLE also