# PostgreSQL dynamic query "query has no destination for result data" returning results

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic

Seems like I'm missing something very basic here. Trying to run a dynamic SQL query that will return a resultset.
if I run this, it will return run successfully, but return nothing:

```
DO $$
<<outerblock>>
DECLARE 
    p_sql text;
BEGIN
    p_sql := 'Select * from public.tbl_song;';
    Execute p_sql ;
END $$
```

if I run this, it will complain that the query has no destination for result data

```
DO $$
<<outerblock>>
DECLARE 
    p_sql text;
BEGIN
    p_sql := 'DO 
                $inner$ 
                BEGIN
                Select * from public.tbl_song;
                END; 
                $inner$;';
    Execute p_sql ;
END $$
```

When I look at the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)  I don't see anything about returning a resultset. Just using a record variable for results, but that's limited to one row.
what am I missing?

Comment: A `do` block can not return a result set

Comment: this should be an answer. Here is another question that I found like it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008181/returning-a-query-from-a-do-block

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because Postgres expects the function to return something of type text, but your function doesn't return anything. The stored procedure won't just return the result of the last SELECT.
You need to actually return the value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun() RETURNS text AS $$
```

BEGIN
--- ....
RETURN(SELECT dblink_disconnect());
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Comment: it's not a function, it's a do block

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to nest `do` blocks, but you can avoid the error by using `perform` instead of `select` in the outer block:

```sql
do $$
begin
perform 'do $_$ begin select 1; end $_$;';
end $$;
```

Comment: it doesn't return a resultset

Comment: DO

Query returned successfully in 45 msec. (this is what it returns)